# Can not connect to service with my public IP, only with localhost

Tags: linux, networking, localhost

I have installed Linux Mint 8 (based on ubuntu). And I have setup a webserver on port 8098.

I can connect to my webserver with `http://127.0.0.1:8098`, but when I try to connect to `http://192.168.1.107:8098` from the same machine or another machine it doesn't work.

How can I get this working? Is there any default firewall settings that I have to change?

Comment: It is a lame guess, but can you ping your 192.168.1.107 address? Also, what webserver are you trying to setup - Apache2? Do you have any firewall rules?

Comment: Yes, I can ping it, but from the same machine and from another machine. The service is a Riak database that uses MochiWeb for the REST interface. I don't know if I have any firewall rules, I just have a default linux mint installation.

Comment: Is your webserver listening to your other IP? Type (as root) `netstat -tupa` on the command line and look for a line that listens on port `80` or `www`.

Comment: @Felix: Thanks, that is the problem, it is listening on localhost:8098. How can I change or add my public IP?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on serverfault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Apache2 ? If so, edit the `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file and change the line to:

```
Listen 80
```

Also you should check the [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#virtualhost) configurations in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` that they look like this (for port 80):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

If you use named virtual hosts, make sure to also add `NameVirtualHost *:80` at the beginning of corresponding configuration.

You can read more about this in the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/bind.html).

(actually this for Debian, but as Mint is based on Ubuntu and Ubuntu is based on Debian this should work).

Comment: Not sure if this applies to your version of linux mint, but on Ubuntu 9.10, you might need to set your firewall to allow access to apache or directly to the port with `sudo ufw allow 8098`

Answer (score 2):

Many services will only listen on localhost by default, and that is the way you want the default to be. Some things to check:

1. Is your web server bound to your loopback interface, or bound to all interfaces?
2. Does your firewall block incoming TCP connections on port 8098?
3. For external access (different subnet), has your router been configured to forward incoming TCP connections on port 8098 to your computer? Your computer should also have a static IP or DHCP reservation if this will be a long term configuration.

Comment: 1. It seam to be bound to my loopback interface when I typed `netstat -tupa` as Felix suggested. How can I change so it listens to all interfaces? 2. I don't know, what is the default firewall in Linux Mint 8 doing? Or how can I check it? 3. OK, but this is on a LAN, so it's all on the same subnet.